# Build library project

Tags: android, jar, android-library

all.
I've created an android library project and it's works perfectly when i reference it from main project. But when i build the library project apart it doesn't contains R.java and resources. Is there way to build a library project with resources and R.java?

Comment: How do you build the library project apart?

Comment: I using NetBeans IDE for developement. Right click on project and selected Build. Result of build is the same as building with the main project - jar file in bin directory of the library project without r file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible now.

Now we can create a binary-only library project via the following steps:

1. Create an Android library project, with your source code and such – 
   this is your master project, from which you will create a version of 
   the library project for distribution
2. Compile the Java source (e.g., ant compile) and turn it into a JAR file
3. Create a distribution Android library project, with the same 
   resources as the master library project, but no source code
4. Put the JAR file in the distribution Android library project's libs/ 
   directory 
   The resulting distribution Android library project will have everything a 
   main project will need, just without the source code.

There is some restrictions in this solution:

1. We still have to ship the resources.
2. We have to rewrite our code to avoid using R. values, as they 
   will be wrong. We will have to look up all resource IDs using 
   getResources().getIdentifier() and/or reflection.

Answer (score 5):

I use Eclipse and never manually build my Android Library Project independently, but I think the development considerations stated on official dev guide [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#considerations) should answer your question:

> **Each library project creates its own R class**
>
> When you build the dependent application project, library projects are compiled and merged with the application project. Each library has its own R class, named according to the library's package name. The R class generated from main project and the library project is created in all the packages that are needed including the main project's package and the libraries' packages.

**Update** with Another note quoted from the official dev giude [Library Projects](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects):

> However, a library project differs from an standard Android application project in that you cannot compile it directly to its own .apk and run it on an Android device. Similarly, you cannot export the library project to a self-contained JAR file, as you would do for a true library. Instead, you must compile the library indirectly, by referencing the library in the dependent application and building that application.

Comment: Thank's. But R file creates in main project, not in library's jar. And resources are not packed into this jar.

Comment: @RomanBlack, Library jar file apart from host project really means nothing. Android Library Project is not referenced as jar file at runtime, instead, its sources (java, res, AndroidManifest.xml, etc.) are compiled and merged into host project when you build host project (by doing this enable Android SDK to filter only the used part into your final apk, resulting reduce apk file size and save memory space), In IDE like Eclipse, R.java with it compiled classes is auto-generated when build host project.

Comment: @RomanBlack, Android dev team is currently revamping Android Library Project design and promise support exporting library project as jar file in next coming release, check out [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2011/10/changes-to-library-projects-in-android.html) for more details.

Comment: Yes, i know. But i have to create android library with closed source code as jar file. It's impossible to create the library that includes R-file and resources and share it. Now i find a way to share compiled source code, but my resources is open source.